# rabbitmqadmin [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: debian, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin

So I keep getting "connection refused" from rabbitmqadmin. I'm running debian 7 on a vm as root user. I installed rabbitmq-server with apt-get, started it up and did the following:

```
rabbitmqctl add_user test 1234
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags test administrator
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / test ".*" ".*" ".*"
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

cd /usr/local/bin/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/rabbitmq_v3_5_6/bin/rabbitmqadmin
chmod +x rabbitmqadmin

rabbitmqadmin -H 127.0.0.1 -u test -p 1234 list vhosts
```

But the call to rabbitmqadmin always results in *Could not connect: [Errno 111] Connection refused*

I have tried the following:

- restarting the service (/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server
  restart/stop/start)
- verified that rabbitmq-management is enabled via *rabbitmq-plugins list* and checking */etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins*
- verified that rabbitmq-management actually started by checking *rabbitmqctl status* and the rabbitmq logs
- removing/reinstalling rabbitmq-server
- removing/reinstalling rabbitmqadmin
- i checked that 127.0.0.1 was in fact listed in */etc/hosts*

I tried *rabbitmqadmin list users* and I get the same problem. I'm pretty stumped, any ideas?

note: i'm not sure if it's relevant, but i had some trouble getting rabbitmq-server installed, i kept getting "unmet dependencies" issues and running *apt-get -f install* would remove some other packages that i needed. i think the problem actually came from installing erlang, and eventually got it working by going through the tree of unmet dependencies and installing each of them one at a time until erlang and rabbitmq-server were both installed.

ALSO i added "deb http://http.debian.net/debian wheezy-backports main" to */etc/apt/sources.list* so i also tried removing rabbitmq-server, removing the repo, apt-get update and reinstalling rabbitmq-server, still nothing.

Comment: did you tried to access using the browser ? `http://localhost:15672/`

Comment: So I eventually gave up and managed to get it running by using CentOS and the "barebones" version of erlang that rabbitmq provides on their website.

Answer (score 10):

on debian 10, rabbitmq-server installed a lot of plugins, but enabled none by default.

you may list them as root with:

```
rabbitmq-plugins list
```

then you may:

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

now you may run, as non-root user:

```
rabbitmqadmin list queues
```

and even

```
rabbitmqadmin delete queue name=rpc_queue
```

i did no special configuration.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows as well. It also enabled the admin management via browser at localhost:15672/

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution:

`rabbitmqadmin` needs to talk to the management-website of the server. The same which you use as an admin. The default seems to be TCP `port 15672`, but the config that I am using (also Debian, but 9) is `port 8080`.

I found which port the management-interface runs on by looking into `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config` where I found this:

```
       {rabbitmq_management, [{listener, [{port, 8080},
```

You could probably also try to check which open ports belong to the rabbitmq-server and try them all.

Finally, to use this information, I have created a config-file for rabbitmqadmin under `~/.rabbitmqadmin.conf` and filled it with the info found in the output of `rabbitmqadmin help config`. (It might be important to remove leading spaces.)

Answer (score 0):

just remove: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
and restart the service